# Can't get my pointers to send a reference to the array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int* getEvenNumbers(int arr[], int N)
{
    int i, k = 0 , a[50], p;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
       {
           if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
              arr[k]=arr[i];
               k++;
            }
       }

      return arr[k];
}



int main ()
{
int i, arr[5000000], N, a[500000], k, *p;

    printf("\nEnter your desired length of the array:\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        arr[i]=  rand();

    getEvenNumbers (arr, N);

        printf("\n\nEven numbers in the array are as follows:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
        a[i]= *(p+i);
      printf("\n[%d] = %d", (i+1), a[i]);
        }
}
```

please i know this is probably very easy for you guys but i need help figuring out how to return a pointer to the array without all my values of my array getting deleted, also i can't use global variables and it has to be a function that returns a pointer pointing to the array

Comment: `arr[5000000]` Stack Overflow?

Comment: You are modifying the array. Then why are you trying to return something. And the returned value is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, decrease the size of those arrays, you don't need that much space. Second of all, you made your

> getEvenNumbers

function return an `int *`, and not an `int`. `arr[k]` is not an `int *`. I also don't get why you are returning something if nothing is being assigned when you call the function. You can just change the return type to `void`.

> void getEvenNumbers(int arr[], int N)

You also never allocate any memory for `p`. You can do

> p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));

And since you never allocated any memory for `p`, the following line of code

> a[i]= *(p+i);

is assigning `a[i]` to a random address. You should just try to rewrite this program. There a **lot** of errors in this program that I didn't even correct. Go on Google an look up `finding even numbers in array program` or something similar and look at the code of those examples.

EDIT:

I found some code examples for you to use. I hope it helps!

[StackOverflow](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36505/finding-odd-and-even-digits-from-an-integer)

[sanfoundry.com](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-odd-even-number-array/)

Comment: Good advice. The only is worth clarification is `malloc` is C function and if you really use C++ use `new` operator (and `delete` instead of `free`)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically allocate memory from heap.

```
int* a= new int [N];
//Now store the elements from index 1.
// at a[0] store the number of even number you  have found in this function.
return a;
```

In `main` you know how many even numbers are there.

```
 int *a1=getEvenNumbers(arr,n);
 count_even=a1[0];
 for(index=1;index<=count_even;index++)
   cout<<a1[index];
```

The code is given here-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int* getEvenNumbers(int arr[], int N)
{
    int i, k = 1 ,  p;
    int* a=new int[N+1];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
       {
           if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
              a[k++]=arr[i];
       }
    a[0]=k-1;
      return a;
}

int main ()
{
int i,  N;

    printf("\nEnter your desired length of the array:\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int arr[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        arr[i]=  rand();

    int *a=getEvenNumbers (arr, N);
    printf("\n\nEven numbers in the array are as follows:\n\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= a[0]; i++)
      printf("\n[%d] = %d", (i), a[i]);  
   delete []a;      
}
```

A better option is to use `std::vector`.You can read it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: or use `std::vector` instead

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz.: Yes that's a better option. I will add that also. I don't even understand why he is so interested in returning pointer to array?

Comment: @Brad.: Check my answer, I think this is what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

The caller already knows the address of the array, so you just need to return the new length.  If we also remove the unused variables and take advantage of C++ declarations, we will have:

```
int getEvenNumbers(int* arr, int N)
{
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < N; i++) {
       if (arr[i] & 1 == 0) { // even if lowest bit is zero
          arr[k] = arr[i];
          k++;
       }
    }

    return k;
}
```

Now you can print the even numbers easily:

```
int k = getEvenNumbers(arr, N);

printf("\n\nEven numbers in the array are as follows:\n\n");
for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    printf("\n[%d] = %d", (i+1), arr[i]);
}
```